# How to transfer credentials to Glass from Web

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-glass, google-gdk

Since the "preview" of the GDK is out, I was wondering how we could transfer the credentials of OAuth (say from Twitter) from an AppEngine project (or anything else, open to suggestions) to the APK on Glass. I haven't seen anything on this, and since authentication on Glass would be very hard, how would we do this? I know that I could create a database, but I'm not sure how to make a lightweight version of that. Any other ideas besides a database would be welcome. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to have user login on a website, then save OAuth token into a QR code and let the user scan the QR code with Glass.

I have used it in my app Glasquare (Foursquare for Glass), it's all open-sourced:
https://github.com/destil/glasquare

EDIT: There is official way now: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/authentication

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could login from the smartphone version of your app, and transfer those credentials to your glass generating a QR code and reading that QR first time you enter to your Glass app

Answer (score 0):

The video that was published implied there was a authentication step during install but he also said that 'it was still beign worked out'

The bike app (Streva? May have the spelling wrong) does request some kind of authentication

I should add I'm pretty interested in how to deal with oauth in glass also